# Material Design and punctuation

Tags: material-design

Material design says to [skip periods](https://m2.material.io/design/communication/writing.html#principles) for messages in dialogs which are only one sentence. Yet in [their dialog examples](https://m2.material.io/components/dialogs#anatomy) they use a period in that circumstance. So, which is it?

Comment: It says "Any sentence followed by a link (links themselves should not be full sentences)" The example has links following it. Is that what you're talking about? Miss it?

Comment: No, it's in the "Skip unnecessary punctuation" section.

Comment: Yeah, that's from the Skip Unnecessary Punctuation section:

"Use periods on:

Multiple sentences
Any sentence followed by a link (links themselves should not be full sentences)"

Answer (score 1):

You are right that most of the examples on that [dialog page](https://m2.material.io/components/dialogs) ignore the punctuation rule. It could be outdated examples. That page however doesn't address punctuation so I would follow the rules described on the [page about writing](https://m2.material.io/design/communication/writing.html). There is stated:

> Avoid using periods on solitary sentences within these UI elements:
>
> - ...
> - [Dialog](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html) body text

A funny fact is that "Dialog" in that text is a link that refers to the top of the dialog page where the first example is the only right example.

[image]

Later the page about writing refers to a different section of the dialog page. (the one referred to by the OP). From there you only see the "wrong" (lets assume outdated) examples.

> The following components have specific writing guidance:
>
> - [Dialogs](https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#anatomy)
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this, here are two sentences: *Reset settings?* and *This will reset...*

[image]

I assume that the rule is exclusive to single sentences:

Comment: "Reset settings" is a header. I really don't think they mean to include headings when talking about single vs multiple sentences.